# Handling several .one on same event and element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a custom animation framework that uses CSS transitions.

In order to allow for callbacks I attach:

```
$element.one('webkitTransitionEnd transitionend',function(){
    $element.css({
        '-webkit-transition':'',
        /* And so on... */
     });

    if(callback){
        // This is to make sure that chained events are not fired before the styling is flushed to the DOM, otherwise some animations will not have css transitions
        setTimeout(function(){
            callback(); 
        },0);
    }
});

$element.css({
    '-webkit-transition':'height '+duration+'s ease-out',
    /* And so on... */
    });
$element.css('height',height);
```

However, some of the same event listeners are fired again and again (yes, it's actually the same functions with the same guids, I checked). It seems the `.one` is not properly removing it again.

I've tried making a small test-fix with a:

```
var used = false;

$element.one('webkitTransitionEnd transitionend',function(){
    if(!used){
        used = true;
        /* Rest of function... */
    }
}
```

and I get several catches using the boolean to keep track if they have been fired, so I keep them from re-firing at least. But I'd like to know why they are re-firing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt that both `webkitTransitionEnd` and `transitionend` is beeing fired so you would end up with a lot of unused events bound on your elements. I would unbind the event instead of binding using `.one`:

```
$element.on('webkitTransitionEnd transitionend', function() {
    $element.off('webkitTransitionEnd transitionend', arguments.callee);
});
```

Note that the above example doesn't work when using `"use strict"`. Then you should use:

```
$element.on('webkitTransitionEnd transitionend', function handler() {
    $element.off('webkitTransitionEnd transitionend', handler);
});
```

Not sure if it solves your problem. But you could try.

#### What is:

[`arguments.callee`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments/callee)
[`"use strict"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode)

Comment: you'll want to consider namespacing your handlers so you're not accidently unbinding other handlers as well as your own.

Comment: It works like a charm. Both events are fired in chrome, while only the transitionend event is fired in firefox adding extra confusion in my case. Removing both events on one of the fired events was the solution :-)

Comment: @jbabey I only unbind my own handler when passing it in as the second argument to `.off(events [,selector] [,handler()])`. http://api.jquery.com/off/